# Nesting IIF in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm writing an expression which needs to calculate the number of days between current report rundate and the date value in field (named cmp_lastap), then return a value of:

- "delinquent" if the number of elapsed days is `>= 60`,
- "past due" if `>= 45` and `<60`,
- "due" if `>30` and `<45` and
- "current" if `<= 30`.

It seems that a nested IIF statement is what I need to use, but something is off and I can't figure out what I've done wrong:

`=IIF(DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Fields!cmp_lastap.Value, Today) >= 60,"DELINQUENT", IIF(DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Fields!cmp_lastap.Value,Today) > 45 AND <60, "PAST DUE", IIF(DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Fields!cmp_lastap.Value, Today) > 30 AND <=45, "DUE", IIF(DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Fields!cmp_lastap.Value, Today) <= 30, "CURRENT")`

Any help or suggestions for other expressions to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use AND like that, you would have to say `[date comparison logic] > X AND [date comparison logic] < Y` etc...

**However**...
I find nested IIF's get messy quickly especially if you have more than one condition to test so I prefer to use `SWITCH`

Using switch you could write it like this.

```
=SWITCH (
    DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Fields!cmp_lastap.Value, Today) >= 60,"DELINQUENT",
    DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Fields!cmp_lastap.Value, Today) > 45,"PAST DUE",
    DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Fields!cmp_lastap.Value, Today) > 30,"DUE",
    True, "CURRENT"
)
```

Another nice side effect is that `SWITCH` stops at the first expression that evaluates to `True` so we don't need to test ranges. The final `True` acts like an `ELSE`

**Note** I've not tested or checked you date logic but assuming that is sound then the above will work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to test for less than. Short-circuit bool evaluation is being used.

```
=IIF(DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Fields!cmp_lastap.Value, Today) >= 60, "DELINQUENT",
    IIF(DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Fields!cmp_lastap.Value, Today) > 45, "PAST DUE",
        IIF(DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Fields!cmp_lastap.Value, Today) > 30, "DUE",
            "CURENT")
    )
)
```

You can also use a `CASE` statement which may prove more readable.